# Android emulator doesn't start. Screen is just black/see through

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

### Specs

OS: Lubuntu 18, based on Ubuntu 18

Android Studio - About

```
Android Studio 3.1.3
Build #AI-173.4819257, built on June 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-24-generic
```

linux command: lscpu

```
Virtualization:     AMD-V
```

linux command: kvm-ok

```
INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
```

---

### Explanation

Hello,

I am having trouble getting the Android Studio emulator to run.

All the settings I can find says that the emulator should be able to run.

Virtualization looks to be enabled, kvm looks to be installed and enabled, my user is a member of the kvm group

I have tried with various setups for the emulators, adjusting the internal storage space, SD card storage space, switched emulation between software and hardware, tried other phone types and emulation images.

But none of it works.

All that happens is that the emulator frame starts up, the phone screen itself is either black or see through (varies). Android studio keeps saying that it awaits for the device to be online.

I did get a warning message saying that the ADB i use is obsolete and they recommend upgrading it. But it just said that otherwise it would be slower.

I have not yet found out how to make this upgrade. It might be the cause of it but somehow I think I should get a different message then.

A trace of errors I do get are these ones from the event log:

```
9:47 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3

9:47 PM Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]9:47 PM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3

9:47 PM Emulator: Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.1 [bit 19]

9:47 PM Emulator: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.sse4.2 [bit 20]
```

But I am not sure what that means.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

UPDATE:

If I use the command

```
$ sudo adduser `id -un` libvirtd"
```

I get the message

```
adduser: The group `libvirtd' does not exist.
```

I can add to libvirt but not libvirtd which the tutorials on installing svm suggest. I have tried to install libvirt with the commands they say but am told by the CLI that none with that name exists.

Comment: did you got any solution ??

Comment: Unfortunately no. I stopped working on that solution.